# Regex to delete lines with a certain amount of dots?

Tags: regex, match, notepad++, line

I want to delete lines with 3 or more dots. I tried to delete it myself but it deletes all lines with dots while I need only lines containing 3 or more.

For example

```
p..z.e.4c.e.u.j abc1
aaaaaa 11111
ju.as.h.e.s 125.60.000.
p.iv.p.f.j abcde
r.g.9c 11111112
o.u.n.ggz 12..345.6
ffffffff 22222
1.2.3.45 abcddd
ddddddddddd 33333333

to this result

aaaaaa 11111
r.g.9c 11111112
ffffffff 22222
ddddddddddd 33333333
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*(?:\..*?){3}.*(?:\R|\Z)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
  .*            # 0 or more any character but newline
  (?:           # non capture group
    \.          # a dot
    .*?         # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  ){3}          # end group, must appear 3 times
  .*            # 0 or more any character but newline
(?:\R|\Z)       # non capture group, any kind of linebreak OR end of file
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Comment: Find: `^((.*\..*){3,})\s`    → Replace with `nothing`